# How to convert string to date in sql query?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I am using MS-SQL Server. I am getting an exception near the `Convert`. Here is my query:

```
String query1="select * from pat.dbo.Demand_Register 
               where (select (Convert (datetime,Payment_Date,103)) as pd 
                      from pat.dbo.Demand_Register)
                  between '"+frmDate1+"' and '"+toDate1+"' ";
```

And the Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Syntax error converting datetime from character string.
```

Comment: First of all you are missing Double Quotes, it should be like this `'" + frmDate1 + "'`

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Syntax error converting datetime from character string                     this exception occured.

Answer (score 1):

It probably because you concatenating your string using single quotes there should be double quotes as well; look at how your combining `frmDate1` and `toDate1` parameters in your string.

So this should work

```
String query1 = "select * from pat.dbo.Demand_Register where (select  (Convert(datetime,Payment_Date,103)) as pd from pat.dbo.Demand_Register) between '" + frmDate1 + "' and '" + toDate1 + "' ";
```

Comment: that was a good observation, generally hard to find, but i guess that might not be the point, as his IDE(if he is using one) might make that obvious to him

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is unnecessary complex, you can simplify that to:

```
String query1="select * from pat.dbo.Demand_Register " +
               "where Convert (datetime,Payment_Date,103) " + 
               "between '"+frmDate1+"' and '"+toDate1+"' ";
```

But this is still not a good idea. You should be constructing `java.sql.Date` instances from `frmDate1` and `toDate1` and use them in a PreparedStatement:

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.sql.Date from = new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(frmDate1));
java.sql.Date to = new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(toDate1));
String query1="select * from pat.dbo.Demand_Register " +
               "where Payment_Date between ? and ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement();
stmt.setDate(1, from);
stmt.setDate(2, to);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

That not only will you protect you from SQL injection, it might also be faster as a potential index on `Payment_Date` can be used.